# Variances in angular.module(....) function calls

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. Sometimes I see:

```
 angular.module(...)....
```

Sometimes

```
 var app = angular.module(...)...
```

Sometimes the latter is wrapped in an IIFE.

When is it appropriate to use either one of the first 2? What real difference do they make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Approach** : with

```
var app = angular.module(...)...
```

you are saving a reference to the returned module instance and reuse it to register multiple service/configs/providers etc

so you will call methods on this like

```
     app.config(); 
     app.controller();
```

etc

**2nd Approach** : with this

```
angular.module(...)
```

you are chaining methods with dot in between them because angular.module(...) , contollers, providers returns module instance that can be chained

like

```
  angular.module("sm",[]).config(function(){}).controller()... so on
```

**Comparison/drawbacks/Advantages** :

With first approach drawback is that we declare an "app" intermediate variable that could end up in global namespace if we dont use IIFE

```
(function() { 
     var app = angular.module(...)...
 } )()
```

So we can use  angular.module("...") with each controller/factory etc but that could be much of the repetition

luckily, we can use the second approcach to chain,because angular.module(...) , contollers, providers returns module instance

Answer (score 3):

Most style guides regarding angular recommends the first variant since you never really need to define a variable to reference the module.
You can access a module with `angular.module('moduleName')` like so:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController' , SomeController);

function SomeController() { }
```

I recommend this [style guide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide)

Comment: Thanks for the John Papa link

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference but style you write your project.

Consider following example that demonstrate both cases you mentioned:

**`angular.module(...)`**

```
angular.module('myApp.', [])
.value('version', '0.1')
.service('apiFrontendService', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ }
.factory('localFactory', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ }
.controller('MyController', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ }
```

and so on. Here we *chain* our services one after another.

**var app = angular.module(...)...**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.', []);
app.value('version', '0.1');
app.service('apiFrontendService', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ };
app.factory('localFactory', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ };
app.controller('MyController', ['$http', function($http) { /* */ };
```

Here you define once `app` and you can use it over all your project

Answer (score 0):

Latter is used to define a global variable to store application's main Angular module. So, code can be splitted into files.

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('testApp');

// aController.js
app.controller('aController', ...);

// bController.js
app.controller('bController', ...);

// someService.js
app.service('seriousService', ...);
```